# Crystal report Dynamic image display from database

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports-2008

i have written a code to display image of employees in crystal report. In database image path of the employees are stored and am converting those images to byte array and binding that to report and its throwing

"Invalid Argument provided. Failed to open a rowset. Error in File C:\Users\jyothik\AppData\Local\Temp\IDCard {5BCC8A08-330A-4C48-82DE-8F57365D60DB}.rpt: Invalid argument for database."
error.

Any help will be great full and report works fine if i dont bind that image filed.